# Convert datetime to other runtimetype in flutter app

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, custom-data-type, flutter-moor

I'm trying to convert a `DateTime` runtimetype value to `Expression<DateTime, DateTimeType>`. I've been trying to achieve this for almost three days now. I have tried different approaches but non is working.

The reason I want to achieve this is because [moor_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter) library in some cases uses and accepts the library's **custom** `runtimetypes` on methods and and the parameter values on those methods.

Below is the sample code;

```dart
final DateTime dateToday = new DateTime.now(); // convert DateTime to Expression<DateTime, DateTimeType>
var dateWithNewRuntimetype; // assign the converted value to this variable
```

I thought I fixed this issue by adding `as as Expression<DateTime, DateTimeType>` to the value of `dateWithNewRuntimetype` variable value but no this is not the solution either.

The solution will work on the code below

```dart
Stream<List> getLoansWithTomorrowDueDate(int dayInFuture) {
    return (select(loans)
          ..where((l) => l.due_date.isBetween(
              dateToday, // it should be Expression<DateTime, DateTimeType> not DateTIme
              futureDate, // it should be Expression<DateTime, DateTimeType> not DateTIme)))
        .watch();
  }
```

If you want me to provide more info on this I will do so.

Thank you, so much Love.

Comment: What is custom runtimetypes ?

Comment: I simply mean the `runtimetype` is not default one for dart eg: `String`, `DateTime` etc.

Comment: What type do you want?

Comment: @Kahou I want to convert `DateTime` to `Expression<DateTime, DateTimeType>`

Comment: What is `Expression` and `DateTimeType` ?

Comment: I'm new to flutter so I do not understand much stuff but `Expression<DateTime, DateTimeType>`  type and similar types eg: `Expression<int, intType>` these are all custom runtimetypes used by moor_flutter package in some cases when you are working with this package.

Comment: Please show your codes.

Comment: @Kahou I have updated the code.

Comment: @Kahou Check the code agian, I have simplified it. That's the code I can provide for now.

Comment: What is `loans` ?

Comment: @Kahou `loans` is an sqlite table. `$LoansTable get loans => db.loans;`

Comment: Use `isBetweenValues`, instead `isBetween`.

Comment: Ok, Thanks man I appreciate it. It is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isBetween` is compared with`SqlType`.
You must use `isBetweenValues`.

```
/// Defines extension functions to express comparisons in sql
extension ComparableExpr<DT, ST extends ComparableType<DT>>
    on Expression<DT, ST> {

  Expression<bool, BoolType> isBetween(
      Expression<DT, ST> lower, Expression<DT, ST> higher,
      {bool not = false});

  Expression<bool, BoolType> isBetweenValues(DT lower, DT higher,
      {bool not = false});
}
```